# Discontinuous functions that are continuous on every line in ${\bf R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

This is exercise 7 from chapter 4 of Walter Rudin *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, 3rd edition. (Page 99)

Define $f$ and $g$ on ${\bf R}^2$ by: $$f(x,y) = \cases {0,&if $(x,y)=(0,0)$\\
xy^2/(x^2+y^4) &otherwise}$$

$$g(x,y) = \cases {0,&if $(x,y)=(0,0)$\\
xy^2/(x^2+y^6) &otherwise}$$

Prove that:

1. $f$ is bounded on ${\bf R}^2$
2. $g$ is unbounded in every neighborhood of $(0,0)$
3. $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$
4. Nevertheless, the restrictions of both $f$ and $g$ to every straight line in ${\bf R}^2$ are continuous!

This is one of the few specific problems I remember from my university career, which ended some time ago. I remember it because I toiled over it for so long and when I finally found the answer it seemed so simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Consider $0\le {(x\pm y^2)}^2 = x^2 \pm 2xy^2 + y^4$, so $\pm 2xy^2\le x^2+y^4$, and $(\pm2)f(x,y) = (\pm 2){xy^2\over x^2+y^4}\le 1$ since $x^2+y^4$ is non-negative. Taking the negative sign gives $f(x) \ge-\frac 12$ and taking the positive sign gives $f(x)\le\frac12$.
2. Let $B$ be given, and consider the value of $g$ at the point $((1/3B)^{-3}, (1/3B)^{-1})$. At this point $g$ takes the value $\frac{1\vphantom{(1/3B)^{-5}}}{2\vphantom{(1/3B)^{-6}}}\frac{(1/3B)^{-5}}{(1/3B)^{-6}} = {\vphantom{(1/3B)^{-5}}3B\over \vphantom{(1/3B)^{-5}}2}$, which is strictly larger in value than the given $B$.
3. Consider the restriction of $f$ to the semiparabola $P=\{(y^2, y), y>0\}$. $f$ is easily seen to have the constant value $\frac12$ everywhere on $P$, which includes points arbitrarily close to the origin.  But $f(0,0) = 0$, so $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.
4. $f$ and $g$, being rational functions with nonzero denominator, are continuous everywhere except at the origin, so their restrictions to lines that do *not* pass through the origin must be continuous.  We therefore need only consider lines through the origin.

   Every line through the origin is either the $y$-axis, with $x=0$, or has $y=mx$ for some $m$. We want to show that each of these restrictions takes values close to 0 in the vicinity of the origin, to agree with $f(0,0) = g(0,0) = 0$.

   The restriction of $f$ to the $y$-axis is the constant function $f(0,y) = 0/y^6 = 0$ everywhere except at the origin, which agrees with $f(0,0)=0$, so $f$ is continuous on this line; $g$ is similarly zero everywhere on the $y$-axis.

   For other lines $y=mx$, we get $f(x,mx) = \frac{m^2x^3}{x^2+m^4x^4} = \frac{m^2x}{1+m^4x^2}$, and it is easy to see that $\lim_{x\to0} f(x,mx) = 0$, since the numerator goes to zero and the denominator to 1.  $g(x,mx)$ is similar: $\lim_{x\to0}g(x,mx) = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{m^2x^3}{x^2+m^6x^6}=  \lim_{x\to0}\frac{m^2x}{1+m^6x^4} = 0$.

I remember I dealt with sections 1 and 4 quickly, but then suffered over section 3 for hours before I hit upon the idea of looking at the parabola $P$.  After this, section 2 was easy, because the idea is basically the same: look at the restriction of $g$ to the set $\{(y^3,y), y\in{\bf R}\}$.

Comment: What else can I learn from this?  I did not hand in most of my analysis homework that semester, and my professor quite reasonably told me that if I wanted to pass, I had better hand it in. So I was doing a semester of analysis homework in a day or two, and was under a lot of time pressure. Had I been able to sit and let the problem marinate in my mind for a few days, probably the parabola would have occurred to me spontaneously.  But I had squandered that opportunity. Moral of the story: do not leave all your analysis homework until the last week of classes.

Comment: Note to self: (2) needs elaboration. You need to show that for any given neighborhood of $(0,0)$, for any given $B$, there is a point $p$ in the neighborhood at which $g(p)>B$.

Answer (score 1):

For (3), you might notice that for $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$,  $f(x,y) = xt/(x^2 + t^2)$ where $t = y^2$, and for any given $2R^2 = x^2 + t^2$ you can maximize $f(x,y)$ by taking $x=t=R$, getting $f(R,\sqrt{R}) = R^2/(R^2 + R^2) = 1/2$.